# Tag Wars: The Science Fiction/Fantasy Tag Cleanup Event

Tags: discussion, retagging

Below are links to the various elements of the tag cleanup event.

- [Initial Proposal](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7761/2816) - Motivation and goals.
- [Target Tag Nominations Round One](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7871/2816) - Round one tag selection ***[completed 1/15/2016](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7952/2816)***
- [Tag Cleanup Round One](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/tag-cleanup-2016-before-the-burnination) - Cleanup efforts for round one tags ***[completed 1/15/2016](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7952/2816)***

Some tag discussions are large enough to justify separate meta discussions before being rolled into the cleanup even; these are:

- [Media Tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7893/2816) - Discussing use of media tags
- [Actor/Cast Tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7901/actors-cast-and-casting) - Discussion of these tags. ***cleanup is completed***
- [Work/Franchise/Author Tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-individual-works-tags-vs-author-tags-vs-franchise) - Discussion of when and how to use these types of tags

Comment: Some [epiphanies](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27057526#27057526) take longer than others, it seems :-)

Answer (score 7):

The First Sci-Fi/Fantasy Tag Cleanup Event -- such as it was -- has been completed.

It was a very small one; myself and @DVK cleaned up 31 questions tagged [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) and 4 questions tagged [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) in preparation for those tags being deleted.

Overall, the following tags have been, or will soon be, deleted by SE Staff:

- [plot-inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency)
- [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation)
- [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death)
- [70s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s)
- [80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s)
- [90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s)
- [plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot)

Voting for round two will start soon.

Comment: OK. Seems to be a lot of pretty biting remarks that observers assume are aimed at me lately, which OPs later think weren't supposed to be biting or aimed at me or both. You're in good company :)

Comment: guys, stop biting DVK!

Comment: @Mooz - I only have one thing to say. And it's a link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=26904137#26904137. If that person doesn't get suspended for that, ...  whatever.