# Tag Cleanup 2016: Before the burnination

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging, burnination

We've got a pretty good thread running down various tags that should be removed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup).  However, before I submit a request to SE to have them removed, we need to do some sanity checking.  From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/158781):

> ### Start by cleaning up the edges
>
> Bad tags are often harbingers of bad questions. So if you're about to remove a bad tag, start by removing the bad questions it collected: find closed questions and delete them, find downvoted questions and close them (if they warrant it), find poorly-written questions and re-write them (if they deserve it). You get the idea.
>
> When a tag is merely ambiguous, sometimes it makes more sense to just replace it with another tag, or one of a number of other tags. This can be a quick way of turning a bad tag into a good one, or at least accomplishing something other than raw destruction when removing it.
>
> This cleanup is easily the hardest, most time-consuming part of the process. Document your progress here on meta, so that others can see what you're up to and get involved - many hands make light work! And again, if you don't think it's worth doing then just drop it and move on to something else.

There are several tags that there's clear consensus should be removed, but there's no indication that someone's done this cleanup work.  To be clear, the tags that need this check are:

- *All gone!*

For each of these (excepting maybe [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death)), make a post here documenting the work done to check that it's okay to remove the tag completely.  Once each has been checked, we'll have the tag removed.

---

#### Nuked

These tags are gone now:

- [70s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s)
- [80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s)
- [90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s)
- [plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot)
- [plot-inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency)
- [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation)
- [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death)

Comment: What was the justification for burninating [tag:plot-explanation]?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7875/1027

Comment: Personally, I don't see the motivation for a massive tag cleanup at all.   For example, for the decade tags, I don't see what the harm of them is.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Take it to the [relevant discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup).  This post is specifically about ensuring the tag purge doesn't leave a mess.

Answer (score 8):

[plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) originally had 140 questions tagged.

Of those:

- 115 already have a franchise, work, or author tag on them, so **superfluous**
- 7 are also tagged [story-identification], so **superfluous**.
- 3 closed questions with no more relevant tag:

[If you drink nothing but holy water, are your bodily fluids holy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22262/if-you-drink-nothing-but-holy-water-are-your-bodily-fluids-holy)

This is closed as "not constructive" but would probably be on-topic today. What do we usually tag these "first X to show Y" questions with these days?

[Ejected into space -- survival tactics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/ejected-into-space-survival-tactics)

This is not only off-topic, but it's a dupe of another off-topic question. The only relevant tag is [science](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science), which is not one of my favorites but so far, not on the chopping block. Should we delete this question, or just remove [plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot) from it?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/anything-known-about-the-plot-in-david-weber-jane-lindskolds-upcoming-book-t

This question is about a specific work of fiction, but it has no tag and no other questions on the site, and the question itself was speculative and no longer relevant (it asks for speculation about the plot of a book published in 2014.

- 13 questions need to have a franchise/work/author tag added to them. **in progress - 2 fixed**
- 2 questions that were not actually about plot, and have been now been fixed to have proper tags: **fixed**

[Science Fiction plot resource (website)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/science-fiction-plot-resource-website)

[What is a retcon, or retroactive continuity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/what-is-a-retcon-or-retroactive-continuity)

Comment: We've lost the plot (tag). There are now [3 untagged questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) someone should sort out.

Answer (score 5):

In the cases of the "decade" tags, they are used almost exclusively (with only 2 exceptions) for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions. In those cases, the tag was superfluous in the first place, and just needs to be removed.

[70s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s): 15 questions, all [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), all of them where [70s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s) was the suspected publication date of the story. **All superfluous.**

[80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s): <strike>75</strike> 74 questions. 73 of them [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), where [80s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s) was the suspected publication date of the story. 1 where the question happened to be about a show produced in the 1980s. <strike>1 where the question was a broad question about all cartoons from the 80s. **74 superfluous**. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84909/who-owns-the-rights-to-popular-1980s-cartoons-that-havent-gotten-a-modern-live) can probably be deleted.</strike> **All superfluous.**

[90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s): 45 questions, all; [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), all of them where [90s](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s) was the suspected publication date of the story. **All superfluous.**

Comment: In fact in this case you don't even need SE staff to delete it. A normal site moderator can just merge the tags into `story-identification` which effectively deletes them, too (after the 1 day of having no questions associated with them, of course don't make them synonyms in the process).

Comment: I don't know _how_ you searched, but I saw some more [tag:80s] question without [tag:story-identification]: [5](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s+-story-identification). A couple needed a work-tag, one was a story ID without that tag.

Comment: I searched by "[80s] -[story-identification]"; right now I get 0 results...

Comment: The 70s, 80s, and 90s are now distant memories.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

This cleanup is **done**.

[death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) is ready to go away. All questions that are about a character named Death have a work-specific tag; all others have a valid work tag, story-id tag, or history-of tag as appropriate.

---

It'll probably take a bit more than this one post to deal with [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) properly, but I might as well get the ball rolling.

Most of the [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) questions are about the concept of death. To aid the discussion of whether we want a tag for that at all, most of these questions fit one of the following formulas:

- What can kill X?
- Can X kill someone?
- What does X know about death?
- Why are there so many/few dead people during X?
- Why did X die? (both in and our of universe)
- What happens when X dies?
- Why did this happen after X died?
- How many times did X die?

My personal opinion is that this would *not* be a useful tag.

---

These are all the [death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) questions that happen to be about a specific personification of death:

- <s>[Does Death really exist in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54713/does-death-really-exist-in-harry-potter) [In the Harry Potter Universe, is Death deadly?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56120/in-the-harry-potter-universe-is-death-deadly)</s> now tagged [harry-potter-death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-death)
- <s>[How could the Marauder's Map detect something which Death could not?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65534/how-could-the-marauders-map-detect-something-which-death-could-not)</s> now tagged [harry-potter-death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter-death)
- <s>[What would happen if Rogue touched or was touched by Death (Grim-reaper)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59644/what-would-happen-if-rogue-touched-or-was-touched-by-death-grim-reaper)</s> now tagged [marvel-death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-death)
- <s>[Why does Death work for Dracula in Castlevania?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32919/why-does-death-work-for-dracula-in-castlevania)</s> now tagged [castlevania-death](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castlevania-death)
- <s>[What is the origin of the concept of "reaping" souls?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/what-is-the-origin-of-the-concept-of-reaping-souls)</s> question is closed and has other tags.
- <s>[Not-So-Grim Reaper](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/not-so-grim-reaper)</s> tagged [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) should be enough.

Comment: P.S. This question badly needs a work tag: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34099/why-laurie-in-laurie-strange-things-happen

Comment: Fixed, I think.

Comment: No questions about Terry Pratchett's Death? ᴛʜɪs ɪs ᴍᴏsᴛ ᴅɪsᴀᴘᴘᴏɪɴᴛɪɴɢ.

Comment: @randal'thor None with that tag at least. Clearly we need an [tag:author-death] tag.

Comment: @Ixrec since when have we been able to do tag links from comments? Last time I checked, `[tag:tag-name-here]` didn't work!

Comment: [“O death, where is your victory? O death, where is your sting?”](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2OiYt.png)

Answer (score 0):

The overwhelming majority of [plot-inconsistency](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-inconsistency) questions already have a franchise, work or author tag. There are only four exceptions:

- [In Ernest Cline's Armada, why didn't they use communication relays?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106122/in-ernest-clines-armada-why-didnt-they-use-communication-relays) is about Ernest Cline's "Armada", so we can just make a tag for that
- [Why bring the codex to the center of the Machine?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99665/spoilers-dead-space-3-why-bring-the-codex-to-the-center-of-the-machine) is about Dead Space 3, so we can apply the existing [dead-space] tag to it
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68077/what-coherent-fictional-time-travel-theories-exist is not about a franchise, work or author, but this is a (justifiably) closed question, and it already has the [time-travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) tag
- [Alternate Reality World of the movie the Invention of Lying - Why no fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51939/alternate-reality-world-of-the-movie-the-invention-of-lying-why-no-fiction) is about a movie called "The Invention of Lying", so we can just make a tag for that

In other words, this tag is superfluous everywhere and safe to burninate.

Comment: 3 of those questions have been retagged; the closed one probably can be deleted, but if not, the remaining tags are fine.

Comment: My instinct was to merge [tag:plot-inconsistency] into [tag:time-travel], but I burninated instead.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This cleanup is **done**.

These questions have now all been retagged with work and/or author tags as appropriate. [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) can go away safely.

---

Ok, here is a final list of all [plot-explanation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) questions that need to be retagged before we can burninate the tag. In most cases these will need new work/author tags created. We will work through this list during our first Retagging Event.

Please remember when retagging a question:

- Don't just retag! Fix anything else that's wrong (generic titles, etc.)
- If you need to create a new tag name, check with the chat room (in case someone else needs the same tag) to coordinate names.
- If you make a new tag, give it at least a tag excerpt. (A whole wiki would be ideal, but we can get the wikis later).

This is the working list. Please check the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33865/tagwars) before working on these for guidelines and effort coordinating!

- [Why did Hawkins destroy the Atlantis?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/why-did-hawkins-destroy-the-atlantis)
- [When and why was Regan possessed in The Exorcist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26470/when-and-why-was-regan-possessed-in-the-exorcist)
- [Why are people being trapped, collected and stored in phone boxes in La Cabina?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36578/why-are-people-being-trapped-collected-and-stored-in-phone-boxes-in-la-cabina)
- [What was the significance of the hummingbird in the movie Cowboys & Aliens(2011)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49666/what-was-the-significance-of-the-hummingbird-in-the-movie-cowboys-aliens2011)
- [How did 'Thing' change locations in The Addams Family (TV series)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51184/how-did-thing-change-locations-in-the-addams-family-tv-series)
- ["The Enchanted" 1984 - confused by the plot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52629/the-enchanted-1984-confused-by-the-plot)
- [How does the dagger work in Prince of Persia](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54776/how-does-the-dagger-work-in-prince-of-persia)
- [Why did Remy (the rat from Ratatouille) cook Ratatouille at the end of the movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69457/why-did-remy-the-rat-from-ratatouille-cook-ratatouille-at-the-end-of-the-movie)
- [What happened to the original bodies in Invasion of the Body Snatchers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77294/what-happened-to-the-original-bodies-in-invasion-of-the-body-snatchers)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77561/what-was-martina-and-his-family-in-picking-up-the-pieces-by-pat-cadigan
- [Who is Sammy the Snake's mother?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78881/who-is-sammy-the-snakes-mother)
- [Is there an official plot explanation for the movie U.F.O. (2012)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/is-there-an-official-plot-explanation-for-the-movie-u-f-o-2012)
- [How did Jimmy end up with Freddy the magic flute?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82264/how-did-jimmy-end-up-with-freddy-the-magic-flute)
- [In "The Machine" (2013), why is a soldier burned?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82812/in-the-machine-2013-why-is-a-soldier-burned)
- [In Professor Layton vs. Phoenix Wright what is responsible for the car accident?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83398/in-professor-layton-vs-phoenix-wright-what-is-responsible-for-the-car-accident)
- [In Steins;Gate (The Show), how does the first D-mail change the universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85384/in-steinsgate-the-show-how-does-the-first-d-mail-change-the-universe)
- [Bruiser's Phone Call](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85465/bruisers-phone-call)
- [What was the box in The Bullet Catcher's Daughter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86002/what-was-the-box-in-the-bullet-catchers-daughter)
- [What is the relationship between the Loc-Nar and the Taarakians?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87063/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-loc-nar-and-the-taarakians)
- [What is the nature of the Grinning Gargoyle at the end of Disney's "The Hunchback of Notre Dame"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87470/what-is-the-nature-of-the-grinning-gargoyle-at-the-end-of-disneys-the-hunchbac)
- [How do we reach Ultima?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91601/how-do-we-reach-ultima)
- [What was the AI's answer in the film: The God Question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97597/what-was-the-ais-answer-in-the-film-the-god-question)
- [Can somebody explain to me the ending of Foxglove Summer (PC Peter Grant #5)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99401/can-somebody-explain-to-me-the-ending-of-foxglove-summer-pc-peter-grant-5)
- [Why were VP's proxies sabotaged in David Marusek's "Cabbages and Kale"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100519/why-were-vps-proxies-sabotaged-in-david-maruseks-cabbages-and-kale)
- [In "Avengers Grimm", is there any explanation for Ernst coming back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102011/in-avengers-grimm-is-there-any-explanation-for-ernst-coming-back)
- [Why does Superman fly headfirst?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102105/why-does-superman-fly-headfirst)
- [How are humans infected in Prey by Michael Crichton?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102347/how-are-humans-infected-in-prey-by-michael-crichton)
- [Question about The Fountain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102695/question-about-the-fountain)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103364/what-does-the-climax-of-carlos-fuentes-novel-vlad-mean
- [In Rice Boy, what were the fulfiller's three changes of form?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110267/in-rice-boy-what-were-the-fulfillers-three-changes-of-form)
- [Why didn't Tiny Tim die?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111671/why-didnt-this-person-die)

Comment: Just so it's obvious what happened: I removed [plot-explanation] from 574 posts.

Answer (score -1):

[`[00s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/00s): 0
[`[10s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10s): 0
[`[20s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/20s): 0
[`[30s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/30s): 0
[`[40s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/40s): 0
[`[50s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/50s): 0
[`[60s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/60s): 0
[`[70s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s): 15
[`[80s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s): 69
[`[90s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s): 45

[`[70s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s) [`[70s] -[story-identification]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/70s+-story-identification): 0
[`[80s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s) [`[80s] -[story-identification]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/80s+-story-identification): 0
[`[90s]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s) [`[90s] -[story-identification]`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/90s+-story-identification): 0